# Selecting control by ID in JS when ASP.net returns only the name

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am using ASP.net and IE8. I'm trying to select an HTML element using document.getElementById() in JavaScript by passing it a control's ClientID property.

The problem is that the ClientID property returns the 'name' and not the 'id'. IE8 is strict about document.getElementById() **only** selecting id's and not names.

So how do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you refer to the name of the element with [getElementsByName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp?)

Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine IE8.
Can you elaborate more about your problem? What is the control your using?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategory" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <script>
        function ShowValue() {
            alert(document.getElementById('<%=txtCategory.ClientID %>').value); ;
        }
    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="ShowValue()" />
```